# python - ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_19 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm building a CNN with keras that classifies facial expressions into 7 categories, that works like a charm, the problem is that when I try to reduce my dataset to only 2 facial expressions I get the error on the title:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_19 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I'm not sure why my model is falling to an array of shape (1,) when I reduce the problem like that, here's my model:

```
@staticmethod
def buildDeeperCNN(width, height, depth, classes, n, m, l2rate, dropout_rate):
    # Initialize model
    model = Sequential()

    # Define inputShape and configure format to match keras'
    if(K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first'):
        input_shape = (depth, height, width)
        chan_idx = 1
    else:
        input_shape = (height, width, depth)
        chan_idx = -1

    # First block
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = input_shape,
                     padding = 'same', strides = 1, use_bias = True,
                     kernel_initializer = 'he_normal',
                     bias_initializer = 'he_normal',
                     kernel_regularizer = l2(l2rate),
                     bias_regularizer = l2(l2rate)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = chan_idx))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))

    # Second block
    for n in range(0, n):
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = 'same', strides = 1,
                         kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                         bias_initializer='he_normal',
                         kernel_regularizer = l2(l2rate),
                         bias_regularizer = l2(l2rate)))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = chan_idx))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))

        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding = 'same', strides = 1,
                         kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                         bias_initializer='he_normal',
                         kernel_regularizer = l2(l2rate),
                         bias_regularizer = l2(l2rate)))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = chan_idx))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))

        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = 2))
        model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))

    # Third block
    for n in range(0, m):
        model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = 'same', strides = 1,
                         kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                         bias_initializer='he_normal',
                         kernel_regularizer = l2(l2rate),
                         bias_regularizer = l2(l2rate)))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = chan_idx))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))

        model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding = 'same', strides = 1,
                         kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                         bias_initializer='he_normal',
                         kernel_regularizer = l2(l2rate),
                         bias_regularizer = l2(l2rate)))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = chan_idx))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))

        #model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = 2))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = 1))
        model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))

    # Fourth block
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                    bias_initializer='he_normal',
                    kernel_regularizer = l2(l2rate),
                    bias_regularizer = l2(l2rate)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = chan_idx))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))

    model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                    bias_initializer='he_normal',
                    kernel_regularizer = l2(l2rate),
                    bias_regularizer = l2(l2rate)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = chan_idx))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))

    model.add(Dense(128, kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                    bias_initializer='he_normal',
                    kernel_regularizer = l2(l2rate),
                    bias_regularizer = l2(l2rate)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis = chan_idx))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))

    # v-- If I print 'classes' I get 2 as expected
    model.add(Dense(classes))
    print('model_classes: ', classes)
    model.add(Activation("softmax"))

    return model
```

I've tried to search for this particular issue to no avail, I'm not sure why keras tries to make my classification fall into an array of shape (1,) insted of shape (2,) since I'm specifying my last layer to have two nodes. Any help on solving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems you are feeding the model with labels of shape `(?,1)`. What is the shape of train labels? If you want to perform binary classification then the number of classes is two but one unit in the last layer is enough, with sigmoid activation of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the problem indeed, I was using sklearns' label binarizer and when you only have two categories it falls into a vector of shape (1,) and there's no way of changing that, I modified the label vector for the reduced case and it is currently working. Really appreciate the answer since this project is due tomorrow hahaha